# is it possible to restrict remote machines to connect to NamedPipeServerStream?

Tags: c#, remote-access, named-pipes

i wanted to know if it's possible to restrict remote machines to access named pipe in a server.
i'm initializing the server as follows:

```
 NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("myPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,  PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

the remote client does:

```
 using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(serverIP, "myPipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    pipeStream.Connect(2000);
}
```

and of course it succeeds.
is there a way to restrict it?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! 
you need to restrict the usage of NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK:

```
PipeSecurity PipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();            
        PipeAccessRule AccessRule = new PipeAccessRule(@"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny);
        PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule);
        PipeAccessRule AccessRule2 = new PipeAccessRule(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName), PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
        PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule2);
```

then add it to the ctor:

```
 NamedPipeServerStream m_PipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("myPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 0, 0, PipeSecurity);
```

note that when using the pipe security, its not enough to deny network access, but you need to allow access for the current user (or users) that should use that pipe.

```
 string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName)
```

Comment: First of all: You seem to have a copy-paste error in line 3 of your code sample. `m_AccessRule` isn't used in the code, should probably be `AccessRule`. Apart from that, this gives me a `IdentityNotMappedException` on adding the access rule to the `PipeSecurity` object. This suggests that the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK` user doesn't exist on my system, but that's not possible, is it?

Comment: @aRestless fixed it.    how is it possible it doesnt exist in your system? when you try to share a folder, write "network service" in the textbox, it doesnt find it?

Comment: If we're talking about this dialogue: http://puu.sh/iFLJe/1d394791a6.png (german text though) no, it doesn't find it. Even more curious that I'm able to remotely connect to the pipe if I leave `AccessRule` out, but I need (your) `AccessRule2` for the pipe to be accessible at all. Seems like `AccessRule2` allows way more stuff than it should.

Comment: @aRestless we eventually reduced the stuff of the AccessRule2 to PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, which is enough for us. (this solution only solves the network stuff).

is it possible that your "NETWORK" user is somehow called different? this may be the key to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick of blocking remote connections, I too had problems with "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK":

```
var PipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity(); 

var networkSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NetworkSid, null);
PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(networkSid, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
```